# ¿Cómo calcular el factorial de un número en Java usando hilos?

Tags: java, hilos, factorial

Tengo que hacer el factorial de un numero, haciendo en un hilo la primera parte y en otro la segunda, el problema es que funcionan por separado pero al ponerlos juntos no me dan el resultado, me dan otros.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Threads extends Thread {
    private static  int numero;
    private static long resultado;
    public static int i;

    public Threads(int i,int numero, long resultado) {
        this.numero=numero;
        this.resultado=resultado;
    }

    public synchronized void factorial() {
        for(i=Threads.i; i<=numero; i= i+1 ) {
            System.out.println(i   +"x" +resultado);
            resultado= resultado*i;
        }
        System.out.println(resultado);
    }

    public void run() {
        factorial();    
    }

    public static void main (String[]args ) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Factorial del numero: ");
        numero = scan.nextInt();
        Threads hilo1 = new Threads(i=1,((numero/2)), resultado=1);
        Threads hilo2 = new Threads(i=(numero/2)+2, numero, resultado = 
        ((numero/2)+1));
        hilo1.start();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que es la primera parte y que es la segunda? los dos threads reciben diferentes parametros... cual es tu idea?

Comment: Pues la verdad tu algoritmo para calcular el factorial no lo usas nunca. Solo lo declaras y allí lo dejas. Tampoco inicias el segundo hilo. Además en el segundo hilo pasas esto: `(numero/2)+2` ¿De donde sacas eso?. Tienes muchos fallos. Empezando que mezclas alegremente `int` con `long`. Te puedo dar una advertencia, el valor máximo de factorial que puedes calcular en Java usando `long` es 20!

Comment: Parece que esta semana ha sido la de números primos y factoriales. Si aclaras un poco la pregunta y ordenas las ideas te podré responder con gusto. Hace poco respondí una pregunta de optimizar un cálculo de factorial en Java, sin usar hilos. Ahora tu planteas lo mismo usando hilos. Aclara la duda en esta pregunta, para que sea bien recibida. Mientras voy adaptando mi programa para usar hilos y así te respondo.

Comment: Tampoco inicializas `Threads.i`, y con nombres de variables como `i` o `numero`no se sabe qué se supone que hace cada cosa. Y parece que quieres usar el resultado de obtener el factorial (porque se supone que eso es `resultado`, ¿no?)... ¡¡¡Antes de obtenerlo!!!

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr**

La siguiente respuesta intenta explicar el uso de hilos y concurrencia en Java de la manera más simple posible. Se explica un `hack` para realizar el proceso sin concurrencia real y luego se explica la forma de hacerlo con concurrencia.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea calcular el factorial de un número entero usando [*hilos*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html). El resultado final debe ser mostrado en pantalla.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para este ejemplo asumiré que el OP ha hecho los deberes y sabe (tiene conocimiento de) lo siguiente:

- [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)
- [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)

En todo caso, una lectura recomendada es: [Oracle Java Tutorial - Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html), donde se puede aprender lo básico para trabajar con hilos (threads).

Lo primero que vamos a hacer es definir una función que calcule el factorial, pero no será una función tradicional.

**¿Recursividad? *"Primero hay que usar recursividad para usar recursividad"*.**

Una función recursiva para calcular el factorial de un número puede verse así:

```java
long factorial(long n) {
    if(n < 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n*factorial(n-1);
    }
}
```

Esta función desbordaría la pila de memoria rápidamente, además el máximo número factorial (seguro) que podríamos representar usando un tipo `long` sería `20!`. No muy poderosa nuestra función.

**Sin recursividad. No llenemos la pila sin necesidad**

Una función no recursiva simplemente usaría un iterador, así no llenamos la pila, sino que iteramos desde `2` hasta `n` y vamos multiplicando sus términos.

```java
long factorial(long n) {
    long result = 1;
    if(n > 1) {
        for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            result = result * i;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**El tamaño importa.**

Ahora que ya resolvimos el problema de la pila, debemos resolver el problema de la máxima representación numérica posible. Para esto debemos introducir la clase [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) de Java.

Si leemos la documentación vemos que dicha clase soporta la asombrosa cifra positiva de `(2^Integer.MAX_VALUE) - 1`. Si tomamos en cuenta que:

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE => 2.147.483.647
```

Entonces, el valor numérico que podemos representar usando la clase `BigInteger` será tan grande como la capacidad en `RAM` de nuestro equipo. Luego viene el tema de poder mostrar dicho número en pantalla, teniendo en cuenta que el tamaño máximo para un tipo `string` es de `(2^31) -1`. Pero todo esto es harina de otro costal. Para calcular factoriales pequeños (pero más grandes que 20!), nos basta con usar esta clase.

**¿Thread, Runnable?**

Aquí es donde se necesita algo de conocimiento de lo que significa trabajar con *hilos*. Y no me refiero a costuras precisamente.

De forma muy amplia, la idea de *hilo* (*thread* en inglés) se refiere a la posibilidad de usar la capacidad que tiene un ordenador (computador) de realizar múltiples tareas a la vez, es decir, de forma concurrente.

No confundir *proceso* con *hilo*. Si bien podrían asemejarse, porque ambos generan un entorno de ejecución, un hilo requiere menos recursos que un proceso, además de algunas otras diferencias.

Los *hilos* por su parte existen dentro de un *proceso*, y podemos tener tantos *hilos* ejecutándose a la vez, como nuestro equipo soporte.

Para implementar el uso de hilos, vamos a valernos del siguiente patrón:

> Crear, administrar y gestionar directamente el *hilo*, mediante el uso de una instancia de la clase `Thread`.

Una vez que tenemos nuestra instancia de la clase `Thread` debemos definir el código que deseamos ejecutar en nuestro *hilo*. Esto lo conseguimos de las siguientes dos formas:

- Usando un Objeto *Runnable* y pasando dicho objeto como argumento al constructor de la clase *Thread*.
- Creando una clase que extienda de *Thread*, la cual a su vez implementa *Runnable*.

Si bien, ambos estilos son válidos, la diferencia está en que usando un Objeto *Runnable* tendremos  un mayor control sobre lo que deseamos ejecutar en nuestro hilo, y no necesitamos que nuestra aplicación extienda de la clase *Thread*. Aunque para gustos, los colores.

Veremos la forma de hacerlo usando estos dos tipos de aproximaciones.

Sin embargo, en esta primera parte haremos *trampa*. Si bien la idea de calcular el valor de un factorial, usando hilos, es o puede ser muy interesante desde el punto de vista de entender los procesos relativos al uso de *hilos*, existe algo llamado [concurrencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrencia_(inform%C3%A1tica)). Y es que esta primera aproximación, la haré separando los *hilos* y sus resultados, para combinarlos al final. Lo cual no es un proceso concurrente real. Pero servirá para introducirnos al mundo de la concurrencia.

## Hack: sin concurrencia

**Runnable**

Vamos a crear un Objeto *Runnable* y lo llamaremos `Factorial` el cual tendrá las siguientes propiedades y métodos privados:

- `start`: valor inicial desde que se realizará la multiplicación para calcular nuestro número factorial.
- `end`: valor final hasta el cual se multiplicarán los elementos de nuestro factorial.
- `result`: valor calculado por nuestra función factorial.
- `factorial(start, end)`: método que realiza el cálculo del factorial.

Además tendremos los siguiente métodos públicos:

- `Factorial(start, end)`: constructor de la clase `Factorial`.
- `run()`: método que se ejecutará cuando se llame al método `start()` del *hilo*.
- `getResult()`: método que nos devolverá el valor calculado del factorial.

Con esto ya podemos escribir nuestro Objeto *Runnable*:

```java
class Factorial implements Runnable {
  private BigInteger start = BigInteger.ONE;
  private BigInteger end = BigInteger.ONE;
  private BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;

  private BigInteger factorial(BigInteger start, BigInteger end) {
    BigInteger res = BigInteger.ONE;
    if(end.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0) {
      int value = end.intValue();
      for(int i = start.intValue(); i <= value; i++) {
        BigInteger index = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i));
        res = res.multiply(index);
      }
    }
    return res;
  }

  public Factorial(BigInteger start, BigInteger end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
  }

  public void run() {
    this.result = factorial(start, end);
  }

  public BigInteger getResult() {
    return this.result;
  }
}
```

Ahora podemos escribir una aplicación que calcule el factorial de un número por partes. Sin embargo, esto no es un proceso concurrente, y lo veremos más adelante.

Para usar este Objeto y sus propiedades podemos hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

- Se captura el valor introducido por el usuario.
- Se calcula la mitad de dicho valor, para usar 2 hilos: Uno calculará la mitad inferior del valor y el otro la mitad superior.
- Se obtiene el resultado de cada Objeto *Runnable* una vez que el hilo ha finalizado de ejecutarse.
- Se multiplican ambos valores para obtener el resultado final.

El código podría verse así:

```java
public class runnableFactorial{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca un número entero:");
    BigInteger number = sc.nextBigInteger();
    BigInteger half = number.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
    Factorial f1 = new Factorial(BigInteger.ONE, half);
    Factorial f2 = new Factorial(half.add(BigInteger.ONE), number);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(f1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(f2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    try {
      t1.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
      t2.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException e2) {
      e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    BigInteger fact = f1.getResult().multiply(f2.getResult());
    System.out.println("El factorial es:");
    System.out.println(fact);
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

Notemos que al constructor de cada *hilo*, le hemos pasado como argumento el Objeto *Runnable*, El mismo es instanciado con los valores necesarios para que realice los cálculos que necesitamos.

Al final, cuando el *hilo* ha terminado su ejecución, obtenemos el valor almacenado en cada Objeto *Runnable* y los multiplicamos, para obtener así el valor de nuestro factorial.

**Thread**

Para hacer el mismo proceso anterior, sin usar un Objeto *Runnable*, debemos crear una Clase que extienda de la clase *Thread* y que implemente un método `run()`.

Los métodos y propiedades públicas y privadas son iguales, sin embargo nuestra Clase ***extiende*** de la Clase *Thread*, mientras que el Objeto *Runnable* simplemente ***implementa*** la interfaz *Runnable*.

```java
class Factorial extends Thread {
  private BigInteger start;
  private BigInteger end;
  private BigInteger result;

  private BigInteger factorial(BigInteger start, BigInteger end) {
    BigInteger res = BigInteger.ONE;
    if(end.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0) {
      int value = end.intValue();
      for(int i = start.intValue(); i <= value; i++) {
        BigInteger index = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i));
        res = res.multiply(index);
      }
    }
    return res;
  }

  public Factorial(BigInteger start, BigInteger end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
  }

  public void run() {
    this.result = factorial(start, end);
  }

  public BigInteger getResult() {
    return this.result;
  }
}
```

Para implementar nuestro programa usando esta Clase, podríamos escribir algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```java
public class threadFactorial{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca un número entero:");
    BigInteger number = sc.nextBigInteger();
    BigInteger half = number.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
    Factorial f1 = new Factorial(BigInteger.ONE, half);
    Factorial f2 = new Factorial(half.add(BigInteger.ONE), number);
    f1.start();
    f2.start();
    try {
      f1.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
      f2.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException e2) {
      e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    BigInteger fact = f1.getResult().multiply(f2.getResult());
    System.out.println("El factorial es:");
    System.out.println(fact);
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

Nuevamente vemos que para obtener el resultado, hemos multiplicado los valores almacenados en cada Objeto (`f1` y `f2`). Nuevamente, si bien hemos usado hilos, el proceso no ha sido concurrente.

## Concurrencia

La idea tras un proceso concurrente es que podamos acceder a una variable en memoria, desde cada *hilo* que la necesite, y que cada *hilo* no sólo pueda leer un valor actualizado de dicha variable, sino que pueda establecer un nuevo valor, todo esto sin importar cuántos *hilos* se estén ejecutando y logrando que cada *hilo* acceda al último valor que se guardó, es decir, el más actualizado.

Esto nos plantea un reto importante: la sincronización, y aunque sería muy interesante poder explicar todos los aspectos de este reto, eso se escapa al propósito general de la respuesta, que ya es extensa de por sí.

En pocas palabras, la idea es evitar que los hilos solapen sus procesos, lo cual podría producir datos incorrectos.

En este caso en particular, nuestra variable será multiplicada por un valor y este será su nuevo valor asignado. Este proceso implica 3 pasos: *leer el valor actual, calcular el nuevo valor, escribir el valor calculado*. Por lo tanto, y dado que esta operación no es [atómica](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html), tenemos riesgo de solapamiento.

Si nuestra operación fuese *atómica*, podríamos hacer uso de una variable tipo [`volatile`](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/index.html), pero en este caso, usaremos un método de tipo [`synchronized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Si se desea una mejor explicación del proceso de sincronización, se puede consultar la sección [*Synchronization*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) del tutorial de Java.

Lo primero que haremos es crear una clase llamada `Factorial` la cual tendrá una propiedad para almacenar el valor de nuestro factorial, un método para obtener dicho valor y un método *sincronizado* para bloquear su ejecución desde que inicia hasta que termina. Esto nos permite evitar el solapamiento cuando el método es llamado desde un *hilo*, y se traduce en bloquear el acceso o la ejecución a dicho método desde otro *hilo*, mientras haya un *hilo* que posea el acceso al método.

**Clase `Factorial`**

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Factorial {
  private BigInteger factorial = BigInteger.One;

  public BigInteger get() {
    return this.factorial;
  }

  public synchronized update(BigInteger value) {
    this.factorial = this.factorial.multiply(value);
  }
}
```

Observamos que el método `update` ha sido declarado como `synchronized`, por lo cual, cuando un *hilo* llame a este método, no podrá ser llamado por otro *hilo* hasta que su ejecución finalice.

Ahora, podemos crear nuestra clase *Runnable*, la cual tendrá un aspecto parecido a lo que ya habíamos realizado, pero con un ligero cambio. Si nos percatamos, la operación de multiplicación ahora está en el método `update` de la clase `Factorial`, por lo tanto, por cada iteración de nuestro bucle `for` sólo debemos llamar a dicho método, pasando como argumento el valor apropiado.

Otra diferencia, es que a nuestro constructor, ahora le pasaremos una referencia al Objeto `Factorial` que instanciaremos una sola vez.

**Clase `MyRunnable`**

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
  private BigInteger start;
  private BigInteger end;

  protected Factorial factorial = null;

  public MyRunnable(BigInteger start, BigInteger end, Factorial factorial) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.factorial = factorial;
  }

  public void run() {
    if(end.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0) {
      int value = end.intValue();
      for(int i = start.intValue(); i <= value; i++) {
        BigInteger index = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i));
        factorial.update(index);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notemos que en el método `run()` hemos escrito la lógica del cálculo del factorial, y dentro del bucle llamamos al método sincronizado `update()` de nuestra clase `Factorial`.

Una implementación completa de este programa usando este Objeto *Runnable* podría verse como la siguiente:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class ProgramFactorial {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca un número entero:");
    BigInteger number = sc.nextBigInteger();
    BigInteger half = number.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));

    Factorial factorial = new Factorial();
    MyRunnable r1 = new MyRunnable(BigInteger.ONE, half, factorial);
    MyRunnable r2 = new MyRunnable(half.add(BigInteger.ONE), number, factorial);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    try {
      t1.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
      t2.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException e2) {
      e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("El factorial es:");
    System.out.println(factorial.get());
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

Como podemos observar, se crea una única instancia de `Factorial` y la misma se pasa como argumento al constructor de cada Objeto *Runnable*, por lo tanto, ambos *hilos* actualizan la misma variable de forma **concurrente**, y dado que nuestro método de actualización es sincronizado, el resultado será el esperado, sin inconsistencia.

---

- Para comparar resultados de esta implementación se puede visitar la siguiente calculadora en línea para factoriales: [Online Math Tools - Factorial Calculator](https://onlinemathtools.com/calculate-factorial)
- Lectura recomendada: [Java Concurrency and Multithreading Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html)